# What is Lang-Arg in vim?

Tags: key-bindings, visual-mode, insert-mode, normal-mode

I was seeing the docs in `:help map-mode` where I saw that `map!` works for `Insert and Command-line` modes while `lmap` works on `Insert, Command-line, Lang-Arg` But I've never heard of `Lang-Arg` mode. Can you explain to me what that mode is?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: This is a feature that allows one to "map" the normal characters on a keyboard to language specific characters, e.g. latin to cryllic or greek.

---

From `:help language-mapping`:

```
                                                *language-mapping*
":lmap" defines a mapping that applies to:
- Insert mode
- Command-line mode
- when entering a search pattern
- the argument of the commands that accept a text character, such as "r" and
  "f"
- for the input() line
Generally: Whenever a character is to be typed that is part of the text in the
buffer, not a Vim command character.  "Lang-Arg" isn't really another mode,
it's just used here for this situation.
```

There is more info, so please open the suggested help page to read on. See also:

- `:help 'keymap'`
- `:help 'iminsert'`
- `:help 45.5`

---

I did not know this before answering. I did the following steps to find this info:

- `:help map-mode`
- `/Lang-Arg`
- `nn`